# Difficulties in java web programming

Tags: java

Hello to all please I need help, I am very versed with java but I have this project I am working on that needs java web programming skills. I have to establish a platform for web development in java. That already done I have to test if the platform is suitable for bot static and dynamic web applications in java.This is my point of difficulty now for the test

Comment: Read **Head First Servlets & JSP.**

Comment: Thats a bit open-ended. Is this for a project with existing code? If so, which web framework is it using?

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is the project for you then...

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/ try this link

Comment: google.com is a good starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials. I have found these ones by Oracle to be the best. They assume you know very little java and work there way up to the complex stuff.

With out knowing what your project it is very hard to give you specific information.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/tutorialLearningPaths.html

Comment: I have to establish a platform for web development in java and after that, I have to develope a dynamic webpage in java